# Typesafe Config: Overriding values for unit testing purposes

Tags: scala, unit-testing, typesafe-config

In a unit test of a class that requires a `config: Config`, I'd like to declare visually (not in a config file located in another place) the assumed configurations settings for the test.

So for example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
class myClassSpec extends AnyFlatSpec{
  val myTestingConfigForThisTestCase = 3L
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
                .withValue("my-config-path", myTestingConfigForThisTestCase)
  ...
}
```

However, `withValue` expects a `ConfigValue` and there seem to be no implicit conversions between basic types and that.

Any ideas on a simple solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use [`ConfigValueFactory`](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/44f21c31b9bf6ea7879438b216d958637c2bbb09/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/ConfigValueFactory.java) - most likely something like

```
ConfigFactory.load()
  .withValue(
    "my-config-path", 
    ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(myTestingConfigForThisTestCase)
  )
```

This doesn't scale well though - i.e. if you need overriding more than 2-3 settings it gets more boilerplaty than [`ConfigFactory.parseString`](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/44f21c31b9bf6ea7879438b216d958637c2bbb09/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.java) + [`withFallback`](https://github.com/lightbend/config#merging-config-trees):

```
val configOverride = """
{
   my-config-path: $myTestingConfigForThisTestCase
   other-config {
      ...
   }
}
"""
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(configOverride)
   .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load())
```